# Как показать картинку вместо ссылки в Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, img, datatable

Использую datatable для формирования таблиц с вызовом данных с https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/ по ajax.
В графе флаг показывает ссылку, как можно показать картинку?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
    
    <script>
$(() => {
    let obj = [];
    let info = [];
    let infoForTables = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/',
        success: response => {
            for (let i in response) {
                obj.push(`${response[i].alpha2Code} ${response[i].flag} ${response[i].name} ${response[i].capital} ${response[i].population}`);
                for (let j in obj) {
                    info = obj[j].split(' ', 10);
                }
                infoForTables.push(info);
            }
            $('#example').DataTable({
                data: infoForTables,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Code" },
                    { title: "Flag" },
                    { title: "Name" },
                    { title: "Capital" },
                    { title: "Population" },
                ]
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(infoForTables)
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а при чём тут тег SVG ?

Comment: флаг-картинка в формате svg, ссылка выглядит примерно так:  https://restcountries.eu/data/and.svg

Comment: Просто обработайте ячейку, в которой у вас хранится ссылка на рисунок https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render